# How to compare two lists and fetch index of the most similar line from both the lists in python?

Tags: python, list, fuzzywuzzy

I have two lists -

```
list1 = [
    "Scarlett Ingrid Johansson is an American actress",
    "The world's highest-paid actress in 2018 and 2019 and she has featured multiple times on the Forbes Celebrity 100 list",
    "Time magazine named her one of the 100 most influential people in the world in 2021",
    "Scarlett Johansson was born on Nov. 22, 1984 in Manhattan, New York",
    "Her father is an architect originally from Denmark",
    "Her mother is a New Yorker who has worked as a producer"
]

list2 = [
    "Scarlett made her film debut in the fantasy comedy North (1994)",
    "She was born in 1984 on November 22nd in Manhattan of New York City",
    "Johansson shifted to adult roles in 2003 with her performances in Lost in Translation"
]
```

How do I compare both lists and fetch index of the most similar line from both the lists?

I've wrote logic for the same but at single string level -

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

str1 = "Scarlett Johansson was born on Nov. 22, 1984 in Manhattan, New York"

found = []

for h in list2: #list2 is from above
    d = fuzz.token_set_ratio(str1,h)
    found.append(d)

list_of_elems = found
elem=max(found) # highest similarity value: 77

index_pos = list_of_elems.index(elem)

print(f"First Index of element {elem} in the list: ",index_pos) # elem = 77, index_pos = 1
print(list2[index_pos]) #She was born in 1984 on November 22nd in Manhattan of New York City
```

This gives me output as expected when str1 gets compared to list2.

How do I get the index of the most similar line from both the lists if instead of str1 I have list1?

Note: list1 and list2 will always have only one value appearing similar (as highlighted in bold in above example).

**Expected output**

```
print(index_pos0) # 3
print(index_pos) # 1
print(list1[index_pos0]) #Scarlett Johansson was born on Nov. 22, 1984 in Manhattan, New York
print(list2[index_pos]) #She was born in 1984 on November 22nd in Manhattan of New York City
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` to get all of the combinations of items from list1 and list2. You can then use `fuzz.token_set_ratio` as the `key` in a call to `max` for the products returned.

```
from itertools import product
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

str1, str2 = max(
    product(list1, list2), 
    key=lambda pair: fuzz.token_set_ratio(*pair)
)
print(str1)
print(str2)
```

```
Scarlett Johansson was born on Nov. 22, 1984 in Manhattan, New York
She was born in 1984 on November 22nd in Manhattan of New York City
```

Comment: This solution helps with the problem statement. Thank you :)